# Emmet-VSCode custom class attribute abbriviation expansion for CSSmodules

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

With VSCode built in Emmet `div.mycssclassname` expands to `<div className="mycssclassname">`

But, because I'm using Webpack with CssModules enabled I need `div.mycssclassname` to expand to `<div className={classes["mycssclassname"]}>`

A snippet like the [riov8 answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57503159/1318601) works for individual tags, which is really nice, but it won't work in a complicated Emmet string expansion

In VSCode the "JavaScript React" syntaxProfile already expands . to className. How can I modify that? where is the syntaxProfile logic?, or can I create a [custom Filter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) to post process the . expansion further ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a normal snippet in `html.json`

```
{
    "Webpack Class": {
        "prefix": [
          "wpc"
        ],
        "body": [
          "<${1} className={classes["${2}"]}>${3}</${1}>"
        ],
        "description": "Webpack tag with a class"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative to emmet, snippets are very useful.